# Creating Custom Icon in Android System main Screen

Tags: android

An Icon should be popup in the main screen , if you go to any of the screen in Android system, 
How to create the Application like that..

Link : [Click here for the Applicaltion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zbWFydC5zd2tleSJd)

Comment: Have a look on this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881597/android-appwide-view-overlay-hud

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the launcher icon, which is displayed on the home screen and apps menu along with the name of your app. To set the launcher icon, write the following in the manifest file

```
 <application
    android:icon="<icon_location>"
</application>
```

[tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/set-your-applications-icons)

Comment: Have a look on this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881597/android-appwide-view-overlay-hud

I have answered for the same type of question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229626/how-to-get-application-menu-over-a-currently-running-screen

Comment: I am looking for Floating Menu in thescreen, I need to use that screen on touch on that portion, irrespective of the screen i am in.